# Can axios request wait until the response is received?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, axios

I need to get IP address and port number details from an external source. These details are required to make some other requests. Following is the code I am trying on:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

let ServerURL

axios.get('http://some/path')
  .then((response) => {
    ServerURL = 'http://' + response.data.server_ip_address + ':' + response.data.server_ip_port
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: ServerURL,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})

export default {
  getConfigInfo () {
    return apiClient.get('/config')
  }
}
```

My problem is that by the time the exported function `getConfigInfo()` is called, still, the `ServerURL` is undefined.

How can I handle this kind of problem? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: call your second function inside the `then` of first function

Comment: Problem here is that I need to export a function only after I get the response. And I cannot export inside `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

let apiClient;

const getApiClient = async () => {
  if (apiClient) {
    return apiClient;
  }

  const {
    data: {
      server_ip_address: ipAdress,
      server_ip_port: ipPort,
    }
  } = await axios.get('http://some/path');

  const serverUrl = `http://${ipAddress}:${ipPort}`;

  apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: ServerURL,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
}

export default {
  async getConfigInfo() {
    const apiClient = await getApiClient();

    return apiClient.get('/config')
  }
}
```

Pattern used: [singleton](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual_articles/singleton-design-pattern-in-javascript)